# Getting data from codeigniter variable using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the data I processed from an ajax request. Basically what I did was I submitted a form using AJAX in my codeigniter application, and I'm trying to get the data I sent from my controllers.

My Ajax Request:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var urlz = obj.attr('action');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlz,
    data: $('#acct-profile').serialize(),
    success: function(d){
alert(d);
        }});    
    });
```

My Codeigniter controller:

/* after adding all of the data I need from my controller */

```
        $this->load->view('account-head');
        $this->load->view('panels/header-in');
        $this->load->view('account/account-main',$userdetails);
        $this->load->view('panels/footer-in');
```

However when I check to see if its working properly, I see that the database is updated, but there is no alert message plus when I check if it sent the data I added in the controller, it's not adding either.

What seems to be the problem of my request?

Comment: What does the full controller method look like? Hard to tell from just showing the loading of the views.

Comment: We need to see the full AJAX controller method you're calling.

Comment: Yes, may be 'echo' or 'return' can solve your problem but still need to check code instead of just loading view.